# Is it a good practice to keep reference in a class variable to the current instance of it?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class that will always have only 1 object at the time. I'm just starting OOP in python and I was wondering what is a better approach: to assign an instance of this class to the variable and operate on that variable or rather have this instance referenced in the class variable instead. Here is an example of what I mean:

## Referenced instance:

```
def Transaction(object):
    current_transaction = None
    in_progress = False
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.current_transaction = self
        self.__class__.in_progress = True
        self.name = 'abc'
        self.value = 50

    def update(self):
        do_smth()

Transaction()

if Transaction.in_progress:
    Transaction.current_transaction.update()
    print Transaction.current_transaction.name
    print Transaction.current_transaction.value
```

## instance in a variable

```
def Transaction(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'abc'
        self.value = 50   

    def update(self):
        do_smth()

current_transaction = Transaction() 
in_progress = True

if in_progress:
    current_transaction.update()
    print current_transaction.name
    print current_transaction.value
```

Comment: I would recommend using Singleton pattern: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to see that you've encapsulated too much in the first case just by comparing the overall readability of the code: the second is much cleaner.

A better way to implement the first option is to use class methods: decorate all your method with @classmethod and then call with Transaction.method().

There's no practical difference in code quality for these two options. However, assuming that the the class is final, that is, without derived classes, I would go for a third choice: use the module as a singleton and kill the class. This would be the most compact and most readable choice. You don't need classes to create sigletons.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first version doesn't make much sense, and the second version of your code would be better in almost all situations. It can sometimes be useful to write a `Singleton` class (where only one instance ever exists) by overriding `__new__` to always return the saved instance (after it's been created the first time). But usually you don't need that unless you're wrapping some external resource that *really* only ever makes sense to exist once.

If your other code needs to share a single instance, there are other ways to do so (e.g. a global variable in some module or a constructor argument for each other object that needs a reference).

Note that if your instances have a very well defined life cycle, with specific events that should happen when they're created and destroyed, and unknown code running and using the object in between, the context manager protocol may be something you should look at, as it lets you use your instances [in `with` statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

```
with Transaction() as trans:
    trans.whatever()       # the Transaction will be notified if anything raises
    other_stuff()          # an exception that is not caught within the with block 
    trans.foo()            # (so it can do a rollback if it wants to)

foo() # the Transaction will be cleaned up (e.g. committed) when the indented with block ends
```

Implementing the context manager protocol requires an `__enter__` and `__exit__` method.